# setCurrentTab Android

Tags: android

i have 4 tabs on **my main screen**,

main ( set to current ) , Call, Email, Web

When a user clicks on any of tab call, email or web, it starts making a call, or go to compose a email, or opens up the browser respectfully.

**Problem** is, i want just three tabs  (Call, Email, Web) and **i Dont want any tab to be selected by default**, means they should only become active when a user Touch them..(a call or any service cant be main at all)

All java coding, XML file, and Manifest code is given below,

**XML File** (tab_activity_layout)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="5dp">
    <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
             />
                  <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:padding="5dp"></FrameLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

**Java Coding** (MainTabActivity)

```
package com.NVT.android;

import android.app.TabActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TabHost;

public class MainTabActivity extends TabActivity{

        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.tab_activity_layout);

            Resources res = getResources(); // Resource object to get Drawables
            TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();  // The activity TabHost
            TabHost.TabSpec spec;  // Resusable TabSpec for each tab
            Intent intent;  // Reusable Intent for each tab

            // Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)
            intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Main.class);

            // Initialize a TabSpec for each tab and add it to the TabHost
            spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("main").setIndicator("Main",
                              res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_artists_grey))
                          .setContent(intent);
            tabHost.addTab(spec);

            TabHost host=getTabHost();

            host.addTab(host.newTabSpec("one")
                    .setIndicator("Call")
                    .setContent(new Intent(this, CallService.class)));

            host.addTab(host.newTabSpec("two")
                    .setIndicator("Email")
                    .setContent(new Intent(this, EmailService.class)));

            host.addTab(host.newTabSpec("three")
                    .setIndicator("Web")
                    .setContent(new Intent(this, WebService.class)));

        }

        }
```

**Manifest file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.NVT.android"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">

            <activity android:name=".Main"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
<!--            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter> -->
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".MainTabActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
              <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter> 
        </activity>


        <activity android:name=".Courses">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".CampusMap">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".GettingHere">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".ILoveNescot">
        </activity>


        <activity android:name=".FurtherEducationCourses">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".HigherEducationCourses">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".EmployersTrainingCourses">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".WebService">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".CallService">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".EmailService">
        </activity>








    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: If a tab is not selected ,then what will be focus of your screen?

Comment: as i said, its on my main screen soo i want these tags to act like buttons..

Comment: and main focus will be My Home screen, not the tab buttons, that i will have to do in Manifest file using intents, but when i change the intent filter to main screen instead of tab activity, it simply dont show the tabs anymore !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say you want the tabs to act like buttons - so why don't you just use buttons instead?

When they are pressed, just change the contents of the area above based on the button pressed.

A TabHost requires that one of the tabs is always visible so while it may be possible to do what you want with a TabHost, and playing with the visibility, your code will be simpler and easier to maintain and debug if you just use buttons instead.

EDIT:

I've not tested this, and have written it from memory, but I think it should give a starting point.

layout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="5dp">
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/contentpane"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="5dp">
    </FrameLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        abdroid:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent">
        <Button android:id="@android:id/callbutton"
            android:text="Call"/>
        <Button android:id="@android:id/emailbutton"
            android:text="Email"/>
        <Button android:id="@android:id/webbutton"
            android:text="Web"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

In your `onClick()` for the buttons, set the relevant content view for the contentpane:

```
FrameLayout fl = ( FrameLayout ) findViewById ( R.id.contentpane );
fl.setContentView ( R.id.callservice ); // Or create it programmatically, and use the layout here
```

Comment: hmmm, i am using tab activity to perform this because, i want my home screen to look like this in link below,

Comment: http://wwwm.coventry.ac.uk/app/Pages/iPhoneApp.aspx  now is it possible to use buttons and make them look like as its in the mentioned app, thanks alot :)

Comment: i knew how to do it using buttons already, buh i picked up your answer, i wonder how they developed that tab or whatever on iphone application i gave link 2

Answer (score 0):

```
    host.setCurrentTabByTag(tag);
    host.setCurrentTab(index);
```

use on of the above method

Comment: how that will gonna help, as i want to remove the main tab !

Answer (score 0):

you said "i Dont want any tab to be selected by default", but it's anti-behaviour of a tab component.
The default character of a tab layout is to be select at least one tab. 
Maybe you must redesign your UI, think other UI in the world as, for example, Firefox...

Greetings

Comment: your right Marcos, but nothings impossible for programmers, is it :)

Comment: i bet there will be any solution for this, what i am trying to do is, using Tabs as Buttons :)

Answer (score 0):

Intent i = new Intent(this, SomeActivity.class);

tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("invisible_tab").setIndicator("").setContent(i));

// hide the tab

tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildTabViewAt(0).setVisibility(View.GONE);